# Create Unique Image (GUID to Image)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'd like to do something like SO does with profile pictures of new users. It seems to create a unique image based on a value.

How can I repeatedly create the same unique image from a GUID?

I'm open to doing this on the server, but would prefer a client side solution to create it on the fly.

Something like these:

[image] [image] [image]

**Edit:** How can I repeatedly create the same unique "nice looking" image from a GUID?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for exactly - a 'random' image wouldn't be the same each time. Do you want a deterministic function that takes a GUID as a parameter and generates an image?

Comment: @Widor yes, a function that consumes a `GUID` and returns an image

Comment: this is cool, I'm looking for just this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an [Identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).

I think this post might either give you want you want or give you some sample code to look at in order to generate your own images.

http://www.puls200.de/?p=316

Comment: Sadly the link to the article is no longer available. (that is to Don Park's Identicons)

Answer (score 1):

GUID is byte array - so it is already a raw data for an image if you treat the same data as bitmap.

If your question is "how to create nice image" it is different story.